# How to remove specific css in appendChild?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, appendchild

I have a drag and drop using react, it's working just fine, but the element that i am dragging on my menu has a css like this:

```
.objects {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFF3CC;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: move;
}
```

I use the position absolute to stack 10 elements and with that i can drag 10 times into my drop zone, this also works fine, but it keeps the property position:absolute, so when it renders on my drop zone it stacks again.
I want to remove the css 'position' from it when i do the append:

```
 event.target.appendChild( this.get_id(elem_id) );
```

How can i remove this property so i can display them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code for chaging css properties in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").style.position = "relative";
```

and just in case, the position options are:

- static
- relative
- fixed
- absolute
- sticky

Comment: and if i want to remove the property position?

Comment: you can't, it always has a position setted, i believe the default is 'static'

Comment: and if i want to set more than 1 property? like position and display?

Comment: the variable style has all what you need to do that:
`document.getElementById("myElement").style.display = "block"`

BTW: display is more complex than position, example: if you set display "block" its the same as setting position static, width 100%.